# Why does installing zope.interface fail?

Tags: python, zope.interface

I've been trying to get PyModbus3 to work in Python 3.4 (64 bit) but it fails on it's requirement for the zope interface:

```
C:\Users\jonc\Downloads>pip install zope.interface
Downloading/unpacking zope.interface
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\zope.interface\setup.py) egg_info for package zope.interface

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from zope.interface)
Installing collected packages: zope.interface
  Running setup.py install for zope.interface

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    building 'zope.interface._zope_interface_coptimizations' extension
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\zope.interface\setup.py", line 147, in <module>
        **extra)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 54, in run
        return _install.run(self)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 539, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\zope.interface\setup.py", line 41, in run
        build_ext.run(self)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 52, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\zope.interface\setup.py", line 47, in build_extension
        build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 186, in build_extension
        _build_ext.build_extension(self,ext)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 503, in build_extension
        depends=ext.depends)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 460, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize
        vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcvarsall
        raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
    ValueError: ['path']
    Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\jonc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_Jonc\\zope.in
terface\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\jonc\AppDa
ta\Local\Temp\pip-qpus0inh-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4

creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope

copying src\zope\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope

creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface

copying src\zope\interface\adapter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface

copying src\zope\interface\advice.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface

copying src\zope\interface\declarations.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface

copying src\zope\interface\document.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface

copying src\zope\interface\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface

copying src\zope\interface\interface.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface

copying src\zope\interface\interfaces.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface

copying src\zope\interface\registry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface

copying src\zope\interface\ro.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface

copying src\zope\interface\verify.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface

copying src\zope\interface\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface

copying src\zope\interface\_flatten.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface

copying src\zope\interface\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface

creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\advisory_testing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\dummy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\idummy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\ifoo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\ifoo_other.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\m1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\m2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\odd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\test_adapter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\test_advice.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\test_declarations.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\test_document.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\test_element.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\test_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\test_interface.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\test_interfaces.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\test_odd_declarations.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\test_registry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\test_ro.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\test_sorting.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\test_verify.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

copying src\zope\interface\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\tests

running egg_info

writing top-level names to src\zope.interface.egg-info\top_level.txt

writing namespace_packages to src\zope.interface.egg-info\namespace_packages.txt

writing requirements to src\zope.interface.egg-info\requires.txt

writing src\zope.interface.egg-info\PKG-INFO

writing dependency_links to src\zope.interface.egg-info\dependency_links.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



reading manifest file 'src\zope.interface.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution

writing manifest file 'src\zope.interface.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

copying src\zope\interface\_zope_interface_coptimizations.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface

creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\common

copying src\zope\interface\common\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\common

copying src\zope\interface\common\idatetime.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\common

copying src\zope\interface\common\interfaces.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\common

copying src\zope\interface\common\mapping.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\common

copying src\zope\interface\common\sequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\common

creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\common\tests

copying src\zope\interface\common\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\common\tests

copying src\zope\interface\common\tests\basemapping.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\common\tests

copying src\zope\interface\common\tests\test_idatetime.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\common\tests

copying src\zope\interface\common\tests\test_import_interfaces.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\zope\interface\common\tests

running build_ext

building 'zope.interface._zope_interface_coptimizations' extension

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\zope.interface\setup.py", line 147, in <module>

    **extra)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 54, in run

    return _install.run(self)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 539, in run

    self.run_command('build')

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run

    self.run_command(cmd_name)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\zope.interface\setup.py", line 41, in run

    build_ext.run(self)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 52, in run

    _build_ext.run(self)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run

    self.build_extensions()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions

    self.build_extension(ext)

  File "C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\zope.interface\setup.py", line 47, in build_extension

    build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 186, in build_extension

    _build_ext.build_extension(self,ext)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 503, in build_extension

    depends=ext.depends)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 460, in compile

    self.initialize()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize

    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcvarsall

    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))

ValueError: ['path']

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\jonc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_Jonc\\zope.interface\\setup.py';exec(c
ompile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-qpus0in
h-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jonc\zope.inter
face
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\jonc\pip\pip.log
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Looks like it tries to compile something and can't find MSVC installed and fails because of this. If you have MSVC check if path environment variable set correctly for it or try to install MSVC and run PyModBus installation again

Comment: I do have msvc installed. Any idea what the path environment variable should be set to?

Comment: I haven't used MSVC for ages, it should be in your PATH at least (as far as I remember). Also check this, it might help [Setting the Path and Environment Variables for Command-Line Builds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx)